# Windows Server 2012 R2 Suspending Threads at launch

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server

We're having trouble with processes being marked as "Suspended" in Task Manager and being unable to be killed and/or their related services refusing to stop.  Sysinternals Process Explorer is also unable to resume the process, however through the Properties->Threads tab in ProcExp we're able to resume the RtlUserThreadStart thread and the process continues.

[image: Suspended launch thread]

We initally put this down to being one server and so began migrating services/processes to a new server (we've just moved one service over which spawns cmd.exe threads), however that is also having the same issue.

I've tried using the system Event Viewer in Administrative Tools with a custom event viewer filter to dump out every event for a minute either side of the start time of the thread, but there's nothing in common between the two servers.

The other differences between the two servers is that the first is a Terminal Server whilst the second is set up as a MS SQL Server, and is running only sqlserv.exe.  Both servers are running as Hyper-V virtual machines.

We've never seen this behaviour on any of the other few hundred servers we look after - although I don't believe any of the others are Hyper-V servers - so we're really hoping someone else out there has seen something similar.

Edit: the A/V running on these particular servers is WebRoot

Comment: which AV suite do you use? If I remember correctly Kaspersky caused such an issue earlier this year.

Comment: @magicandre1981 updated the question, its using WebRoot

Comment: does webroot use the Kaspersky scan engine?

Comment: @magicandre1981 not sure, but I don't think so

Comment: stop/remove the VA suite and look if you still have the issue or not

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if etiquette does not allow replies like this..... first time poster.

@EionRobb we have a similar problem with postgre going into suspended status, and some other internally written (admittedly very old) apps doing the same, on Windows 2012 R2. Only started a few weeks ago - no apparent coincidence with any windows updates. Only solution to kill the processes is reboot.
We are running Webroot AV.

Did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: Update: if we stop Webroot, we can kill the suspended process.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please don't leave answers stating that you have the same problem as the one described in the question. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](https://superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: Many thanks DavidPostill! Apologies for the incorrect behaviour.

Comment: It seems WebRoot are aware of this and have released an improvement: https://community.webroot.com/t5/Product-Questions/Update-on-Winlogin-4005-amp-Terminal-Servers-November-22-2016/m-p/276406